# PHP Session to authenticate user access to pages

Tags: php, html, session

I am trying to implement a user login system to my website. I have already made the register login feature and now I am trying to use session to make it so only logged in users can access certain pages, the code for my login page is as follows:

```
<? session_start(); ?>

<div align="left">
    <a href='register.php'>REGISTER&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-  user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <? 
        include('HtmlNavSetupnohome.php');
        include('sqlDeets.php') 
    ?>

    <link href="css/hawthorne_type1_color1.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <h3>USERNAME:</h3><input id="username" type="text" name="username"/>
        <h3>PASSWORD:</h3><input id="password" type="password" name="password"/><br>
        <input class="login" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>

    <?
        include('connect.php');
        if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' and     password='$password'";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                if ($count == 1) {
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                } else {
            ?>

            <br>INVALID LOGIN DETAILS<br>
            <?
                session_destroy();
                $_SESSION['username'] = null;
                }
            }

            if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">location.href =   'http://www.bradleyboothman.co/homepage.php';</script>
            <?
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
            } else {

            }
        }
```

**I tried to use the following on each page I want to protect but had no luck:**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
      // use is not logged in
    } else {
      // user is logged in
    }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? have you checked that you are in fact logged in?

Comment: Have you added `<? session_start(); ?>` at the start of another page ?

Comment: I suggest you put `$count > 0` and why do you set username session twice?

Comment: Sorry but your code has almost all beginner errors: use of the legacy mysql extension that's already gone from the language in PHP/7, wide-open to SQL injection, plain text passwords...

Comment: Jeez holly smokes sql injection!

Comment: I only started coding a few days ago so beginner errors are due to happen.. this is not going to be used for anything other than too learn..

Comment: what an idiot! it was because I wasn't starting session so obviously couldn't use it.. excuses my stupidity. I'd delete it I could

Comment: @braddarb you already started the session in your code right ?

Comment: @braddarb If u have an idea to redirect a user using PHP header function, if SESSION[username] is not set, don't forget to put ob_start(); at the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the MySQL API to count the number of rows in a result-set appears to be a popular approach but also the source of endless questions here. I suggest you actually try to **fetch** a row and:

1. If row found, user is valid
2. Otherwise, it isn't

That also allows to grab other user details you might want to use/display such as user profile, full name, etc. In fact, even username should be displayed as stored in DB rather than as typed in last login.

Your code could use some improvements but I'll give you a piece of advice I consider particularly useful: drop your current learning material (on-line tutorial, book, whatever), which is extremelly outdated and probably not good in the first place, and find something better. At least something that uses PDO, prepared statements and `password_verify()`. Life's too short to learn things you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the SESSION existence every time when you refresh a Page, you can simply use if loop to achieve it.

```
<?php
ob_start(); // to make the below header work

if($_SESSION[username]=="")
{
  header('Location: index.php'); // Redirect to homepage or Login page
}
else
{
  //Do nothing
}

?>
```

Other options are,

Set a new SESSION variable called **$_SESSION[id]** when user logged in.

Delete that SESSION when a user logged out.

And check for the SESSION of ID is empty or not by using the if condition.

```
if($_SESSION[id]=="")
{
  header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    /*
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' and  password='$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    */

    // Let's assume it is 1 (Erase this comment once you test this)
    $count = 1;

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))    {
        if ($count > 0) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            }
          else  {
            echo "<br />INVALID LOGIN DETAILS<br />";
            session_destroy();
            $_SESSION['username'] = null;
            }
        }

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>location.href = 'http://www.bradleyboothman.co/homepage.php';</script>";

    }
      else  {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it dosent work because you destroy ever time your session at the end of your script

Comment: This should be comment not answer